# Erro ao tentar rodar exemplo quickstart oficial do Angular2

Tags: angular

Estou iniciando um projeto para estudo do Angular2, e para tal estou utilizando Debian 8 com node v6.3.1 (npm v3.10.3).

Seguindo o [passo a passo oficial do quickstart do Angular2](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md):

```
#git clone  https://github.com/angular/quickstart  my-proj
#cd my-proj
#rm -rf .git
#npm install
npm WARN lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings install /var/angular2/my-proj
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /browser-sync/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
#
#npm start
```

Ao rodar o `npm start` então aparece uma infinidade de erros:

```
node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts(81,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts(34,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/async.d.ts(35,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(11,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/lang.d.ts(68,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(15,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(16,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(17,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(17,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(18,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(18,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(19,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(19,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts(20,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/common/src/pipes/async_pipe.d.ts(41,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(79,88): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(137,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(196,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts(26,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(115,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(115,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(34,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts(35,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(11,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts(68,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(15,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(16,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(17,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(17,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(18,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(18,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(19,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(19,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/promise.d.ts(20,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/compiler.d.ts(13,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(9,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(13,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(61,148): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(102,144): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(107,139): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/dynamic_component_loader.d.ts(108,135): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/systemjs_component_resolver.d.ts(18,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/systemjs_component_resolver.d.ts(26,53): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/testing/component_fixture.d.ts(77,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/core/testing/test_component_builder.d.ts(74,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts(81,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts(85,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.d.ts(89,99): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts(96,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts(17,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts(34,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts(35,45): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MapConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SetConstructor'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(12,27): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(14,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(15,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(101,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts(11,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts(68,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(9,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(15,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(16,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(17,35): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(17,93): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(18,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(18,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(19,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(19,149): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts(20,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/client_message_broker.d.ts(32,65): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/client_message_broker.d.ts(40,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/shared/service_message_broker.d.ts(35,84): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/web_workers/worker/location_providers.d.ts(21,86): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(10,66): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,60): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(66,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(16,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(17,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(18,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(22,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(24,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(27,40): error TS7006: Parameter 'fixture' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/app.component.spec.ts(28,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(32,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
app/app.component.spec.ts(35,42): error TS7006: Parameter 'fixture' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/app.component.spec.ts(38,43): error TS7006: Parameter 'el' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/app.component.spec.ts(42,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(2,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(7,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(8,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'browser'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(11,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'element'.
e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts(12,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'by'.

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-686-pae
```

Minha pergunta: por quê estes erros estão acontecendo? Como posso resolvê-los?

**Atualização......... 28/07/2016 14:36**

Passou a funcionar após realizar o procedimento descrito por [Rodrigo Rigotti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2081/rodrigo-rigotti)

> Veja se você tem uma pasta typings no seu projeto; se não, rode o
>   comando **npm run typings -- install**. Se sim, tente mudar o atributo
>   "target" no arquivo typings.json para "es6".

Porém, alguns WARNs permanecem ao executar o `npm install`:

```
npm WARN lifecycle angular2-quickstart@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings install /var/angular2/my-proj
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /browser-sync/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14
```

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda para compreender ou resolver estes WARNs.

Comment: Veja se você tem uma pasta `typings` no seu projeto; se não, rode o comando `npm run typings -- install`. Se sim, tente mudar o atributo "target" no arquivo `typings.json` para "es6".

Comment: Agradeço muito pela ajuda! Desta forma funcionou... continuam ocorrendo alguns warns com "npm install"... mas o npm start já está funcionando. Abaixo warns que ainda estão aparecendo.....

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti, aguardo que poste sua pergunta para marcá-la como escolhida.